Getting a lot of errors in this aws-sdk server mainly in websockets
I am getting multiple warning and errors but I am not able to debug them

The delay between the input submitted and the server is extremely long (approx 90 sec) with increases with more emit functions given to it

As I am putting a console.log to see the socket. connection.. there are multiple socket connections happening and then it is showing this error on the console.log of the front end

WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=6So5fa_va5oXey7JAABA' failed:


The getProjectFunction is not giving any output as an array


Index.js (server side)
const http = require('http');
const express  = require('express');
const {Server: SocketServer } = require('socket.io');
const cors = require("cors");
// const { Socket } = require('socket.io');
const { copyS3Folder, fetchS3Folder, saveToS3, getprojectfolders } = require('./awsStart.js');
// const { stringify } = require('querystring');
const {fetchDir, fetchFileContent, saveFile} = require('./fs');
// const path = require("path");
// const fs = require('fs/promises');

const app = express()
app.use(cors());
const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = new SocketServer(server, {
    cors:{
        origin: "http://localhost:3001",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }
})

io.attach(server);
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    // console.log("Someone is here")
    // console.log(socket.id, 'connected');

    socket.on("createStartUp", async (data) => {
        console.log(data)
        await copyS3Folder(`group-source`, `main-dir/${data}`)
    })

    socket.on("fetchStartUpProjects", async (data) => {
        console.log("Fetch Function Recieved",data)
        await getprojectfolders(data, (err, directories) => {
            if(err){
                console.error("There was some error")
            }else{
                socket.emit('directories', directories);
            }
        })
        // await fetchS3Folder(`code/${data}`, path.join(__dirname, `../tmp/${data}`));
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        // console.log('User disconnected');
      });

})

// io.on("connection", (socket) => {
   
// })


server.listen(3000, () => console.log("Server is Running"));


This is the function I am calling (awsStart.js)
async function getprojectfolders(Prefix, callback){
    var params = {
        Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET || "",
        Delimiter: '/',
        Prefix: Prefix,
    };

    s3.listObjectsV2(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          return 'There was an error viewing your album: ' + err.message
        } else {
        console.log(data.CommonPrefixes, "<<< directories");
                      

        var directories = data.CommonPrefixes.map(function(prefix) {
            return prefix.Prefix;
          });
       }
        if (err) {
            callback(err, null);
          } else {
            const directories = data.CommonPrefixes.map(prefix => prefix.Prefix).sort();
            console.log(directories, "<<< directories array");
            callback(null, directories)}
      })

    console.log(directories)

}

This is the front-end which is emitting the function fetchStartupProject
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

export const Login = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [startupId, setStartupId] = useState('');
    const socket = io.connect("localhost:3000");
const navigateRoom = () => {
        socket.emit("fetchStartUpProjects", startupId)
        navigate(`/projectroom/${startupId}`)
    }

}

Finally this is the js file which is supposed to receive the data which is given by the function which is in server-side and map it
import logo from "./logo-closeup-tp.png";
import "./ProjectRoom.scss";
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import toast, { Toaster }  from 'react-hot-toast';
import { useState } from "react";

const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

export const ProjectRoom = () => {  

    const [directories, setDirectories] = useState([]);

    socket.on('directories', (directories) => {
        setDirectories(directories);
      });
}

I tried Chatgpt and it told me to change the getProjectFolders function it is showing a different error

Unexpected end of input

